# Yii scenario not working

Tags: php, validation, yii, scenarios

I'm trying to set up a scenario in Yii. I have a model called File, which I use for a file upload. Now, I want to use the same model for the creation of directories. Directories don't have a file attribute so I setup the scenatio in the model like this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    array('file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png, jpeg, bmp', 'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 10, 'tooLarge'=>'Bestand moet kleiner dan 10MB zijn.'),
    array('file', 'file', 'on'=>'makefolder', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
  );
}
```

In the controller I trigger the scenatio with `$model = new File("makefolder");` Even now I always get the error that 'File cannot be blank'. I used [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) as documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess (because your original code seems fine to me) but you could try to set that the first rule is valid for all the scenarios except `makefolder`:

```
public function rules()
{
  return array(
    array('file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png, jpeg, bmp', 'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 10, 'tooLarge'=>'Bestand moet kleiner dan 10MB zijn.', 'except'=>'makefolder'),
    array('file', 'file', 'on'=>'makefolder', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
  );
}
```

With those rules is the error still here?

But upload a file and create a folder is not the same thing, you should use 2 distincts models!

Comment: Nice! And now I'm not 100% sure the second rule is necessary.

Comment: You're right again, second rule isn't necessary anymore. Thanks!